# Should [source] be eliminated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) has only three questions in it, all of which are over a year old, and [two](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1919/sites-offering-open-source-sound-tracks-music-for-use-in-applications) of [which](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1919/sites-offering-open-source-sound-tracks-music-for-use-in-applications) are closed.  I'm thinking that [source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) should either be eliminated, or defined as a synonym of [source-code](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-code).

Cleanup would be pretty easy:

- [How do I see the source code of Notepad++?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/781/how-do-i-see-the-source-code-of-notepad) — This could be simply retagged [source-code](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-code)
- [Can a novel be open source, although it does not have a source?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/423/can-a-novel-be-open-source-although-it-does-not-have-a-source) – This could also be shifted to [source-code](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-code)
- [Sites offering open-source sound tracks/music for use in applications?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1919/sites-offering-open-source-sound-tracks-music-for-use-in-applications) — This one's sort of awkward, but could probably be retagged [media](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media).

**Should [source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source) be eliminated/synonymed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Ask, and ye shall receive!

The question didn't make sense really, and the only one that it really applied to was your first question, which is closed anyway. So it was a dead tag to start.